# Sort longtext as int in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

The data sorting is not proper and looks like

```
0  
1  
10  
11 2  
20 21  
3
```

here is my order code

```
$select->order('post_meta.meta_value AS int desc');
```

note the `meta_value` field is longtext and not int and cannot change it to fix the problem need another fix.

Comment: Well, you can either add a sorting column or sort it in php.

Comment: how to sort it in php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to your comment question how to sort this in php I can think of something like this:

```
<?php

$stringArray = [0, '1', 10, '11 2', '20 21', 3];

usort($stringArray, function($a, $b) {

    $a = (int)trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $a));
    $b = (int)trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $b));

    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($stringArray);
?>
```